# HTML Dropdown list without changing selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have a HTML/JS dropdown list - I would like the default text in the dropdown box to stay the same even when the dropdown list is changed to navigate elsewhere; please help?!

my code:

```
    <select name="me" id="me" data-theme="a" data-icon="grid" data-inline="true" data-native-menu="true" onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">
        <option value="" selected>DEFAULT TEXT</option>
        <option value="#option1">Option1</option>
        <option value="#option2">Option2</option>
        <option value="#option3">Option3</option>   
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<select name="me" id="me" data-theme="a" data-icon="grid" data-inline="true" data-    native-    menu="true" onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">
    <option value="" selected="true">DEFAULT TEXT</option>
    <option value="#option1">Option1</option>
    <option value="#option2">Option2</option>
    <option value="#option3">Option3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @user2124239 Cannot works cause `true` is not a valid true value. See HTML spec. Only a value matching attribute name or no value at all are valid true value. `selected="selected"`,or just `selected`(no =, no value at all) , `selected='selected'`, `selected=selected` are all considered true, anything else is false.